# Как выделить text-box красным?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, mvc

Нужно если text-box пустой или вводит неправильно значение, вывести сообщение об ошибке и выделить его красным. Сообщение выводится, то что text box пустой. А текст бокс не меняется и сообщение о неправильно вводе не выводится. Как это сделать?
           HTML

```
            <span class="form-control-static">Телефон: </span><span class="notification"> *</span>
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Это поле является обязательным" id="Phone" name="Phone" type="tel" value="" placeholder="8(ХХХ)ХХХ-ХХ-ХХ" pattern="^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
```

В модели

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Это поле является обязательным")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Номер телефона должен иметь формат 8(ХХХ)ХХХ-ХХ-ХХ")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
```

В CSS пишу что бы при нажатии border стал красным

```
input.input-validation-error{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Но не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input:invalid {
    background: #fdd; /* Красный цвет фона */
   }
   input:valid {
    background: #dfd; /* Зеленый цвет фона */
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input.input-validation-error{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Тут написано, что если у инпута установлен класс `input-validation-error`, то отобразить границу инпута красным.
Вы нужному элементу добавте класс `input-validation-error` и его граница станет красной :)

UPDATE

Наверное вопрос понял не правильно... Дело в определении правил для валидатора.
Видимо следующий ответ подойдет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281415/how-to-use-html-validationmessagefor

Или вот: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276853/string-minlength-and-maxlength-validation-dont-work-asp-net-mvc

Comment: можно подробнее, возможно я что то не так делаю

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281415/how-to-use-html-validationmessagefor
Вы должны определить правила для полей, которые вы валидируете.

Comment: подробно описал свои действия